# cannot connect pidgin with ejabberd server

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I have installed Ejabberd server 14.05 on centos 6. While connecting pidgin with ejabberd server i am getting the following error:

> username@hostname/5280 disconnected
>   You require encryption, but it is not available on this server.

in Ejabberd log file:

```
2016-05-25 14:26:15.074 [info] <0.803.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:313 (#Port<0.6031>) Accepted connection 10.88.132.44:55371 -> 10.80.33.144:5222
2016-05-25 14:26:15.095 [debug] <0.1016.0>@ejabberd_receiver:process_data:343 Received XML on stream = <<"<?xml version='1.0' ?>">>
2016-05-25 14:26:15.096 [debug] <0.1016.0>@ejabberd_receiver:process_data:343 Received XML on stream = <<"<stream:stream to='10.80.33.144' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0'>">>
2016-05-25 14:26:15.096 [debug] <0.1017.0>@ejabberd_c2s:send_text:1837 Send XML on stream = <<"<?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' id='1422769748' from='10.80.33.144' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>">>
2016-05-25 14:26:15.097 [debug] <0.1017.0>@ejabberd_c2s:send_text:1837 Send XML on stream = <<"<stream:features><mechanisms xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1</mechanism></mechanisms><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/' ver='A2KZ2CKF+i8zFCXx4QunuiMuMRg='/></stream:features>">>
2016-05-25 14:26:15.110 [debug] <0.1016.0>@ejabberd_receiver:process_data:343 Received XML on stream = <<"</stream:stream>">>
2016-05-25 14:26:15.111 [debug] <0.1016.0>@shaper:update:117 State: {maxrate,1000,0.0,1464166575096830}, Size=16 M=8.0, I=14.137
2016-05-25 14:26:15.111 [debug] <0.1017.0>@ejabberd_c2s:send_text:1837 Send XML on stream = <<"</stream:stream>">>
2016-05-25 14:26:15.111 [debug] <0.1017.0>@ejabberd_socket:send:188 Error in gen_tcp:send: {error,closed}
```

Is there any problem with ejabberd server or is this any networking issue??

Comment: Pidgin is configured to require the server to provide encryption, but the server is not configured with a TLS certificate. To do the latter, see the "Enable SSL/TLS Secured Communication" section is [this tutorial](https://www.ejabberd.im/tuto-install-ejabberd).

Comment: Thanks legoscia, I followed the steps given the tutorial and it worked...thanks alot. Is there any way I can upvote your answer??? I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: I just reposted my comment as a proper answer. You can "accept" it by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pidgin is configured to require the server to provide encryption, but the server is not configured with a TLS certificate. To do the latter, see the "Enable SSL/TLS Secured Communication" section in [the "Install ejabberd" tutorial](https://www.ejabberd.im/tuto-install-ejabberd).